# Is there an algorithm to separate lambda calculus terms using Böhm's theorem?

Tags: lambda-calculus

Böhm's theorem says that given lambda terms $r$ and $s$ with non-equivalent normal forms, there exists $\vec{a}$ terms such that $r\vec{a}=t$ and $s\vec{a}=f$.

I'm finding it hard to determine what those $\vec{a}$ are though. Even separating simple terms like $i$ and $k$.

Is there a procedure one can apply to figure them out?

Comment: This has been [answered recently on CS](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/17928/10336). Note that you can't separate $i$ and $k$, because they have free variables. Böhm's theorem applies only for closed terms.

Comment: I can't quite figure out if the CS answer is just a proof of existence, or it has a simple algorithm built in. However it does seem to use a different, less neat, theorem than the one I'm looking at.

Comment: Also $i=\lambda x.x$ and $k=\lambda xy.x$ don't have free variables.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand that you meant the combinators - the convention is that lower case letters are reserved for variables.

Comment: The Böhm out technique is an algorithm, which proceeds by induction on the structure of the normal forms. For $K$ and $I$, you can give $\vec{a}=KIft$. Then $I\vec{a}=KIft=It=t$ and $K\vec{a}=Kft=f$.